# React and React-Route Link Parameters Not Working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React and React Router, and I'm struggling quite a bit to understand several things, so I'm open to as much education as you are willing to provide. I'm not able to make this work with multiple parameters. I was able to make it work with a single parameter, but not multiple. I get the Whoops404 component. I assume I'm doing something obvious wrong.

My Route:

```
 <Router history={ hashHistory }>   
        <Route path='/' component={ Home } />
        <Route name='details' path='/details/:id:name' component={ Details }/>
        <Route path='*' component={ Whoops404 }/>
 </Router>
```

My Link:

```
 <Link to={`/details/${adv.id}/${adv.name}`}>
      <h1 className="clickTitle">{adv.name}</h1>
 </Link>
```

The Component I'm targeting:

```
export class Details extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        console.log(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `path='/details/:id/:name'` since you're linking to a route with a slash in it.

Comment: That was it. I just couldn't see it. Thanks very much!